# Link to a specific .dll file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, compilation

I have written a C++ program using OpenGl in Visual Studio 2015 for Windows 7.  I compiled my code using "release" instead of "debug".  The program works fine on my computer, but when I move to another computer the program fails.  I get the error message:

The program can't start because MSVCP140D.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I would like for my program to work on other computers so that I don't have to install the newest drivers or libraries in order for it to work.  I have MSVCP140D.dll on my first computer, but I only have MSVCP120.dll on my other computer.  How do I compile my code so that it does not require MSVCP140D.dll, but instead works with MSVCP120.dll?

Comment: *D.dll are debug DLLs, you have your release settings set incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you want it to work with MSVCP120.DLL? You'll need to provide the appropriate DLLs no matter what version of Visual Studio you run. You can't expect any version of these DLLs to be available, whether *140.DLL from MSVC 2015 or *120.DLL from MSVC 2013. Or statically link, as shrike says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your build settings are correct for release build : `MSVCP140D.dll` is the debug DLL of the Visual Studio 2015 runtime; the release version of this libray is `MSVCP140.dll`.

When you've fixed this, then you can install the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) on the target computer where you want to run your program : this will install the missing library. Notice that the VC++ redistributable does not install the debug libraries (`MSVCP140D.dll`) but the release ones (`MSVCP140.dll`).

Another option is to rebuild your program with static linking to the Visual C++ runtime. Open the Project Properties dialog and, in "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation", field "Runtime Library", choose "Multi-threaded (/MT)". This way, there is no need to install the VC++ redistributable on the target computer.

Comment: For others out there - I also had to make sure that I switched my libraries from VC 2015 to VC 2013.  Until I did this, these steps did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Visual Studio 2013 in order to be able to link with MSVCP**120**.dll (you can continue using MSVC 2015, but select 2013 as the toolchain). Once MSVC 2013 is installed, you will be able to select it in project settings -> Platform Toolset.

Or link your application statically (change `/MD` to `/MT` in Code Generation settings). Then your app won't need any MSVC DLL to run (but it will become bigger).

Or install the [VC 2015 Redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) on your other computer.

Comment: Where do I select 2013?  You said it is the toolchain, where is that?

Comment: Once MSVC 2013 is installed, you will be able to select it in project settings -> Platform Toolset.

Comment: Also, if I change to /MT, I get a ton of errors when I compile.  I don't get the errors using /MD

Comment: I installed 2013 and (in VC 2015) I changed the toolchain to use VC 2013.  I was not able to compile, I got 3 errors and 1 warning.  I don't know what to do about them: Error: LNK1120 2 unresolved externals; Error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf; Warning: LNK4098 defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library; Error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf